# unable to get css when sending email with css

Tags: c#, html, css, email

is there any way you can send an email from c# asp.net with a html page with css.

Currently I am sending the email but when I open in gmail it does not capture the css included in the htmlpage

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  <style>
    body{
        background-color:navy;
        color:white;
        font-family:Menulis;
        margin-left:40px;
    }

    div {
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    img{
        border-radius:5px;
        width:200px;
        height:300px;
        margin-right:200px;
        display:block;
        float:right;
    }

 </style>
 </head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>User {user_email} Error Report</h1>
    <p>The following error occured when user is trying to reset password     

  from pswrd_recover.aspx page:</p><br/>
    <img src="https://pcappliancerepair.files.wordpress.com/2016/11 
 /38644550_m.jpg?w=585"/>
    <p>{error_message}</p>

  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail removes the entire **head** portion of your email’s HTML. So, it will also remove any **style** elements. 
You need to inline your CSS, like this:

```
<body style="background-color:navy; color:white;font-family:Menulis;margin-left:40px;">
<div style="margin:0 auto;">...</div>
<img style="border-radius:5px;width:200px;height:300px;margin-right:200px;display:block;float:right;" src="https://..." />
</body>
```

Comment: The `<style>` tag can be used inside the `<body>` element