# Add Font In HTML With CSS

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want add font from url to html with css . I use this html to advertising email template.

I'm adding font from url . but it's not working.

My simple code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Start</title>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'IRANSans';
      src: url('http://dl.itunesmusic.ir/Font/IRANSans-Light.eot');
      src: url('http://dl.itunesmusic.ir/Font/IRANSans-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('http://dl.itunesmusic.ir/Font/IRANSans-Light.woff') format('woff'),
      url('http://dl.itunesmusic.ir/Font/IRANSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div dir="rtl" align="center" style="color:#000;font-family:IRANSans, sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:36px;font-weight:400;">قیمت</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think from memory, most email clients don't support custom fonts? There are only about 6 that you can use reliably in email

Comment: @BenLonsdale You are right, most of the email clients [don't support @font-face](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does @font-face work in email templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303631/does-font-face-work-in-email-templates)

Answer (score 3):

Using inline css not so good practice for web. 
You can use external css using this file like that.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

Also you can generate any font from this site. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Then follow the @DanielaB67 instruction.

Answer (score 0):

**Gmail removes the entire head portion of your email’s HTML. So, it will also remove any style elements. You need to inline your CSS and place the styles inside the body of your html.**
[unable to get css when sending email with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711461/unable-to-get-css-when-sending-email-with-css/44712068#44712068)

If you cannot download the font and upload it to your host, try Google fonts instead. Hope you'll find something similar:
https://fonts.google.com/?subset=arabic

Otherwise, in order to make it work you must download the font, convert it for web and upload it to "fonts" folder in your host.

1. download the font from: http://dl.itunesmusic.ir/Font/IRANSans-Light.ttf
2. go to fontsquirel and convert it to webfont : https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
3. you will get the fonts for webformat in a zip file and a stylesheet.css with the correct names and paths of the font. For example:

   @font-face {
       font-family: 'iransanslight';
       src: url('iransans-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('iransans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;

   }
4. copy and change the font path as you need for each format in your html style section, e.g.('http://www.yourwebsite.com/fonts/iransans-light-webfont.woff2...), and correct the font-family name: e.g. IRANSans to iransanslight. Use absolute path for the fonts: "http://www.yourwebsitename.com/fonts/...", otherwise the fonts will not be downloaded in emails.
5. upload the fonts to your host server and it should work.